# jsonschema library -- schema is not valid?

Tags: python, json, django, validation, jsonschema

I am using the jsonschema library (http://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validate/) in my Django application for server-side validation and am trying to do server-side validation of JSON with a provided schema. However, I get the error that the schema "is not valid under any of the given schemas."

Here is my schema (it is the "scores_ap" property of the "schema" property of the class):

```
class JSONListFieldSchemas:
    """
    Schemas for all the JSON List Fields.
    Each key represents the field name.
    """
    schema = {
        "scores_ap": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
            "title": "AP Scores",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                        "exam": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "score": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "minimum": "1",
                            "maximum": "5",
                            "required": False
                        }
                        }
            }
        }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
{'type': 'object', 'properties': {'score': {'minimum': '1', 'type': 'integer', 'ma
ximum': '5', 'required': False}, 'exam': {'type': 'string'}}} is not valid under a
ny of the given schemas

Failed validating u'anyOf' in schema[u'properties'][u'items']:
    {u'anyOf': [{u'$ref': u'#'}, {u'$ref': u'#/definitions/schemaArray'}],
     u'default': {}}

On instance[u'items']:
    {'properties': {'exam': {'type': 'string'},
                    'score': {'maximum': '5',
                              'minimum': '1',
                              'required': False,
                              'type': 'integer'}},
     'type': 'object'}
```

I am using the schema as follows:

```
from jsonschema import validate
from .schemas import JSONListFieldSchemas
raw_value = [{"score": 1, "exam": "a"}]
validate(raw_value, JSONListFieldSchemas.schema['scores_ap'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From draft 4 and on, "required" should be an array not a boolean.
Also "maximum" and "minimum" should be integers, not strings.

Try like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "title": "AP Scores",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "exam": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "score": {
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 1,
        "maximum": 5
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "exam"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The data in my code was an array though -- or am I declaring it wrong?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, didn't look closely. I'll update my answer.