# Altair returns error with single selector

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Trying to create a slider on the gapminder dataset from vega in Altair.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

from vega_datasets import data

df= data.gapminder()

yearslider = alt.selection_single(
    name="Year",
    field="year",
    init={"year": 1955},
    bind=alt.binding_range(min=1955, max=2005, step=5)
)

alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X("fertility:Q", title=None, scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    alt.Y("life_expect:Q", title="Life expectancy", 



scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    alt.Size("pop:Q", scale=alt.Scale(range=[0, 1000]),
    legend=alt.Legend(orient="bottom")),
    alt.Color("cluster:N", legend=None),
    alt.Shape("cluster:N"),
    alt.Order("pop:Q", sort="descending"),
    tooltip=['country:N'],
).configure_view(fill="#fff").properties(title="Number of children by mother").interactive().add_selector(yearslider).transform_filter(yearslider)
```

Don't know what the error means.

```
altair.vegalite.v4.schema.core.SelectionDef->2->init, validating 'anyOf'

        1955 is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

Updated

Comment: Could you provide a google colab notebook example? - I'm checking this error and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074456/4092887) mentions about the data's structure. Maybe you can post an issue on GitHub or see [anothers posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+is+not+valid+under+any+of+the+given+schemas) related to your error.

Comment: I've uploaded the full code here.

Comment: I've modified your code and added the results. I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is up-to-date - since the documentation says it's deprecated. Maybe if you could prove more info about the version of vega you're using and anything else you consider anyone more knowledgeable can use for help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied the following modifications to your code:

- Removed the attributes from the `selection_single()` - it says on the [release notes](https://altair-viz.github.io/releases/changes.html) `selection_single` and `selection_multi` are now deprecated; use `selection_point` instead.
- Removed code added after the call to `interactive()` function.

Modified code:

```
yearslider = alt.selection_single()

alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X("fertility:Q", title=None, scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    alt.Y("life_expect:Q", title="Life expectancy", 

scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    alt.Size("pop:Q", scale=alt.Scale(range=[0, 1000]),
    legend=alt.Legend(orient="bottom")),
    alt.Color("cluster:N", legend=None),
    alt.Shape("cluster:N"),
    alt.Order("pop:Q", sort="descending"),
    tooltip=['country:N'],
).configure_view(fill="#fff").properties(title="Number of children by mother").interactive()
```

Result:

[image: Chart with data]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

Comment: Actually, what I was saying, is thank you for taking the time to solve an issue.

Comment: What I want to do is put a slider on the chart so that you can view the data year by year. This presents the lot.

Comment: @elksie5000 I'm glad that my alternative is what you need :) Thank you for your compliment and anytime I can be able to help :)